# Why does Firefox think my website is using a tracker?

Tags: http, firefox, mozilla, tracker

After a recent update of Firefox in which they incorporated their own tracker detection and blocking, I am now getting a warning saying that my site is using trackers. I paired the site down to a bare minimum page and it still says this. Is it because it's not using https?

Here is the bare minimum index.html that I have on it:

```
<head>
<title>Welcome to the EC2 Web server</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1>Success!</H1>
</body>
```

Here is a screenshot of its tracker warning:

[image]

I am on Firefox 65.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue disappeared after I did a Facebook refresh. I was getting an error at the bottom of the browser that Firefox was running slowly and it suggested I do a refresh, so I followed the instructions. I'm not 100% sure this fixed the issue, but at least it was not because the page was unsecured.

[image]